# how do I trigger an angularjs service after every nth seconds a user typed something

Tags: angularjs

My user types something. I want to save the typed data after every say 1000ms the user stopped typing.

I do NOT want to use $intervall with 1000ms.

How can I do this using latest angular 1.3.11 ?

Comment: In other words, you want to debounce the effect of the change event.

Comment: `ng-model-options="{debounce:1000}" ng-change="change()"` if you are using 1.3.x you can use debounce option of ng-model. otherwise handle it yourself with a timeout or using libraries like lodash which has [debounce implementation](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce).

Comment: @PSL Thanks for the ng-change hint works better than watching the property !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Angular 1.3

```
<input ng-model='data' ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" />
```

Further information on ng-model-options in the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/#!/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)

In your controller, you can $watch('data') and save your changes whenever data is changed (just like you would if you weren't debouncing the input).

You may also be able to use ng-change instead of $watch, but I haven't tested how that interacts with debounce (but based on other answers, looks like it would work as expected).

Answer (score 1):

In this case, use the change event and the typical way of debouncing an event.

Template:

```
<input type="text" ng-change="valueChanged()" ng-model="value">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.value = '';
var timeout, delay = 1000;
$scope.valueChanged = function () {
  if (timeout) {
    $timeout.cancel(timeout);
  }
  timeout = $timeout(function () {
    // do something
  }, delay);
};
```

don't forget to pass `$timeout` to your controller. What this will do is every time that event is triggered, the previous timeout will be canceled and a new one will start. when the event doesn't happen for `delay` milliseconds, it will complete and call `doSomething`.

Comment: Yeah a handy solution if user is < 1.3.

Comment: Wow, that's a sweet option in 1.3, i'll have to add that to my toolbelt.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$timeout` to schedule the service call after 1 second when the user types something. Cancel the previous $timeout first.

```
var promise;
$scope.userTypedSomething = function() {
    if (promise) {
        $timeout.cancel(promise);
    }
    promise = $timeout(service.method, 1000);
}
```

Another option is to combine the user of getterSetter and debounce in [ngModelOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions), so that a setter, calling the servicemethod,  is called after 1 second of inactivity.