# Optimize ajax calls with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, angularjs-http

I'm creating something like this [example](http://imgur.com/vidgif) but for search proposes, using this code:

```
  $scope.$watch('terms', function(newValue, oldValue) {
      if (angular.equals(newValue, oldValue)) {
          return;
      }

      getResults(); //$http.get...
  });
```

If i write fast it will generate a big amount of ajax calls to my server. But in the example you can see that works very well and the server don't give response to every call (i think that's what happening).

So, the best way to do this and prevent some abuse is to do something on the server-side?

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/28332553/400654

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you on Angular > v1.3 just use ngModelOptions debounce.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

```
<input type="text" name="userName"
       ng-model="user.name"
       ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" />
```

So the update waits e.g. 1000ms until trigger the update.
Should be a good solution for your problem.